# How to create a recyclerview that reads the firestore reference field in Java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when a user adds a song to the favorites, the application saves the reference of the favorite song in a collection called 'favorites', so I would like to create a query to be able to create a recycler view that shows the data of the song that is being referenced.

Music document:

[image]

Document where the music is being referenced:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/firestore/readme/)

It provides a utility class to easily query Firestore data into `RecyclerView`.